# function returning something strange

Tags: c++, return

I have a function to get a grade point value from a grade object and return it as a double as implemented below:

```
double Grade::getNumGrade()
{
    double value;

    if (strGrade == "A")
    {
        return 4.0;
    }
    else if (strGrade == "A-")
    {
        return 3.7;
    }
    else if (strGrade == "B+")
    {
        return 3.3;
    }
    else if (strGrade == "B")
    {
        return 3.0;
    }
    else if (strGrade == "B-")
    {
        return 2.7;
    }
    else if (strGrade == "C+")
    {
        return 2.3;
    }
    else if (strGrade == "C")
    {
        return 2.0;
    }
    else if (strGrade == "C-")
    {
        return 1.7;
    }
    else if (strGrade == "D+")
    {
        return 1.3;
    }
    else if (strGrade == "D")
    {
        return 1.0;
    }
    else if (strGrade == "D-")
    {
        return  0.7;
    }
    else if (strGrade == "F")
    {
        return 0.0;
    }
}
```

With `strGrade` being the string representation of the grade. However with the code here:

```
Grade jon = Grade("A+");

cout << jon.getNumGrade();
```

outputs :

> -1.#IND

The constructor just makes sure the first letter is uppercase and then saves the string provided as `strGrade`. Not sure why this is happening or how to fix it?

Comment: Did you debug it? following your code statement by statement will get you your answer

Comment: Looks like not all of your paths return a value. You should have something like `return 0.0;` before the last closing brace.

Comment: You never handle A+ in your if statements.

Comment: You haven't shown us what the constructor looks like. But either way, @NathanOliver is correct that you are not handling "A+" in your `getNumGrade` function.

Comment: You are surely getting compiler warnings for this function, such as 'not all paths return a value'. Students should have to turn on warnings as errors.

Answer (score 1):

As [NathanOliver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4342498/nathanoliver) pointed out,

> You never handle A+ in your if statements.

See

```
double value;
if (strGrade == "A")
{
    return 4.0;
}
else if (strGrade == "A-")
{
    return 3.7;
}
```

No conditional for when `strGrade == A+.`

But since this was answered in a comment, I'll attempt to justify writing this as an answer by giving you some advice.

Your final conditional,

```
else if (strGrade == "F")
{
    return 0.0;
}
```

shouldn't be an `else if`. There's plenty of good ways to deal with error handling (like an unexpected input) but a very easy yet efficient practice is to end your conditionals with an `else`. For example,

```
//if all other conditionals thus far have returned false
else
{
    ... error handling here ...
}
```

In the event that you fall into this `else`, log an error and/or gracefully exit the program; at the least, *return a value* and handle it appropriately.

---

Also consider applying your `if else` in a logical ordered based on the likelihood of a certain conditional being evaluated to `true`. More specifically, if you *know* that a majority of students are going to get a B+, make that the first expression that gets evaluated in your `if else` series. If a B- is the next most common grade, make that the second expression that gets evaluated; and so on. Additionally, if you know that a grade is *least likely* to be passed through, make that the *last* conditional you check.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thank you very much, I appreciate that. I removed that remark from my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Not sure why this is happening or how to fix it?

That's happening because your function doesn't return a value for the `"A+"` case and exposes undefined behavior.

As mentioned in comments you should have seen a compiler warning about that stating

> > ```
> > Not all of your code paths return a value.
> > ```

You can fix that providing always a (reasonable) return value before your last brace in the function, or throwing an exception for unexpected cases of `strGrade`.

---

BTW the much easier solution would be to use a `std::map<std::string,double>` to hold the associative values:

```
 double Grade::getNumGrade() {
     static std::map<std::string,double> numGrades = {
          { "A",  4.0 } ,
          { "A-", 3.7 } ,
          { "B+", 3.3 } ,
       // ...
     };

     auto found = numGrades.find(strGrade);
     if(found != numGrades.end()) {
         return found->second;
     }
     return 0.0;
 }
```

It also looks that this should be a free or static function rather than a class member function:

```
 double getNumGrade(const std::string& strGrade) {
```